# Not being able to apply HTML/CSS to a simple component in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am picking up React and I am trying to apply Login/Signup code I got from this website: https://codepen.io/khadkamhn/pen/ZGvPLo.

The issue is no matter what I do I cannot get the same animation for tab switching (from Sign In to Sign Up and vice-versa).

My component code is pretty simple:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import './Login.css';
    
    function Login() {
    return (
        <div className="login-wrap">
            <div className="login-html">
                <label htmlFor="tab-1" className="tab">Sign In</label>
                <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" className="sign-in"/>     
                <label htmlFor="tab-2" className="tab">Sign Up </label>
                <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" className="sign-up" />                
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


export default Login;
```

This is embarrassing to ask but I cannot figure out why it's not working as it does in the link above.

Comment: Show us your Login.css style

Comment: @Phil In the link above, there is CSS file. It's the same one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to see animation because you didn't add id to your inputs.

By the way, I have converted that to React.

```
import './Login.css';

function Login() {
    return (
        <div className="login-wrap">
            <div className="login-html">
                <input
                    id="tab-1"
                    type="radio"
                    name="tab"
                    className="sign-in"
                    defaultChecked="true"
                />
                <label htmlFor="tab-1" className="tab">
                    Sign In
                </label>
                <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" className="sign-up" />
                <label htmlFor="tab-2" className="tab">
                    Sign Up
                </label>
                <div className="login-form">
                    <div className="sign-in-htm">
                        <div className="group">
                            <label htmlFor="user" className="label">
                                Username
                            </label>
                            <input id="user" type="text" className="input" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="group">
                            <label htmlFor="pass" className="label">
                                Password
                            </label>
                            <input
                                id="pass"
                                type="password"
                                className="input"
                                data-type="password"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="group">
                            <input
                                id="check"
                                type="checkbox"
                                className="check"
                                defaultChecked=""
                            />
                            <label htmlFor="check">
                                <span className="icon" /> Keep me Signed in
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="group">
                            <input type="submit" className="button" defaultValue="Sign In" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="hr" />
                        <div className="foot-lnk">
                            <a href="#forgot">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sign-up-htm">
                        <div className="group">
                            <label htmlFor="user" className="label">
                                Username
                            </label>
                            <input id="user" type="text" className="input" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="group">
                            <label htmlFor="pass" className="label">
                                Password
                            </label>
                            <input
                                id="pass"
                                type="password"
                                className="input"
                                data-type="password"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="group">
                            <label htmlFor="pass" className="label">
                                Repeat Password
                            </label>
                            <input
                                id="pass"
                                type="password"
                                className="input"
                                data-type="password"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="group">
                            <label htmlFor="pass" className="label">
                                Email Address
                            </label>
                            <input id="pass" type="text" className="input" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="group">
                            <input type="submit" className="button" defaultValue="Sign Up" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="hr" />
                        <div className="foot-lnk">
                            <label htmlFor="tab-1">Already Member?</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}


export default Login;
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    color: #6a6f8c;
    background: #c8c8c8;
    font: 600 16px/18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
    content: '';
    display: table
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    display: block
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none
}

.login-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 525px;
    min-height: 670px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khadkamhn/day-01-login-form/master/img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .19);
}

.login-html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 90px 70px 50px 70px;
    background: rgba(40, 57, 101, .9);
}


.login-html .sign-in-htm,
.login-html .sign-up-htm {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .4s linear;
}

.login-html .sign-in,
.login-html .sign-up,
.login-form .group .check {
    display: none;
}

.login-html .tab,
.login-form .group .label,
.login-form .group .button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.login-html .tab {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.login-html .sign-in:checked+.tab,
.login-html .sign-up:checked+.tab {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #1161ee;
}

.login-form {
    min-height: 345px;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.login-form .group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.login-form .group .label,
.login-form .group .input,
.login-form .group .button {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

.login-form .group .input,
.login-form .group .button {
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.login-form .group input[data-type="password"] {
    text-security: circle;
    -webkit-text-security: circle;
}

.login-form .group .label {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.login-form .group .button {
    background: #1161ee;
}

.login-form .group label .icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.login-form .group label .icon:before,
.login-form .group label .icon:after {
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.login-form .group label .icon:before {
    left: 3px;
    width: 5px;
    bottom: 6px;
    transform: scale(0) rotate(0);
}

.login-form .group label .icon:after {
    top: 6px;
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(0) rotate(0);
}

.login-form .group .check:checked+label {
    color: #fff;
}

.login-form .group .check:checked+label .icon {
    background: #1161ee;
}

.login-form .group .check:checked+label .icon:before {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
}

.login-form .group .check:checked+label .icon:after {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
}

.login-html .sign-in:checked+.tab+.sign-up+.tab+.login-form .sign-in-htm {
    transform: rotate(0);
}

.login-html .sign-up:checked+.tab+.login-form .sign-up-htm {
    transform: rotate(0);
}

.hr {
    height: 2px;
    margin: 60px 0 50px 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.foot-lnk {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the order of input and label matter? I copied your code and changed the order of label and input and it doesn't work anymore.